# Conditions of equal measures in all sigma algebra

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

What i have to prove:

For X and $\mathcal{F}$ not empty let $( X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measureable space with $\mathcal{A} = \sigma(\mathcal{F})$ for a closed under intersection family $\mathcal{F}$ and  $\mu, \nu$ measures:$\sigma(\mathcal{F})$->[0,+$\infty$] , where $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P(}X)$ and $\mu(F)=\nu(F)$ for every F$\in \mathcal{F}$. If there exists disjoint F1,F2,F3,.....$\in \mathcal{F}$ such that X= $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty Fn$  **and** $\mu(F_n)= \nu(F_n) < \infty$ for all $n$ then
$$\mu(G) = \nu(G) ~~\forall G \in \mathcal{A}= 
 \sigma(\mathcal{F})$$

And i know the following theorem for equivalence of measures $\mu(A)=\nu(A)$  for every A $\in \sigma(\mathcal{F})$:

Let $( X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measureable space with $\mathcal{A} = \sigma(\mathcal{F})$ for a closed under $\cap$- family $\mathcal{F}$ and  $\mu, \nu$ be measures on that spaces, where $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P(}X)$ and $\mu(F)=\nu(F)$ for every F$\in \mathcal{F}$. If there exists an increasing sequence $(Fn)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathcal{F}$ such that X=the countable union from n=1 to infinity of Fn **and** $\mu(F_n)= \nu(F_n) < \infty$ for all $n$ then
$$\mu(G) = \nu(G) ~~\forall G \in \mathcal{A}= 
 \sigma(\mathcal{F})$$

a first thought of mine would be to create an increasing sequence with the disjoint sets but ultimately there is nothing that tells us that the term Bn for instance will have finite measure. So, i can't think of an increasing sequence which doesn't do this(unless we can somehow show that it converges and therefore is bounded, could it have to do with taking some sort of intersection of the disjoint sets(?))

I'm starting to think that i have to prove it without creating an increasing sequence and it's probably something more general.I thought of proving that the set in which $\mu(G)=\nu(G)$ is in fact $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$, by showing that it's Dynkin but i think i need the increasing sequence there as well.

Any hints? I would like it if someone could give me a hint perhaps in the comments and of course post the answer for others to see, should they want to do so.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What is $F$ where you write $\mu(F) = \nu(F)$?

Comment: Very unclear statements. Also, isn't this obvious from the definition of a measure?

Comment: @RobArthan you're right sorry. F belongs in $\mathcal{F}$

Comment: @geetha290krm I tried to copy the exercise as is, maybe something got lost in translation(?). Obvious, how?

Comment: It still isn't clear what you mean by "when $F_1, F_2, \ldots$ just disjoint". Please state clearly and separately the hypotheses and conclusion of the theorem you are trying to prove.

Comment: @RobArthan I made a few changes. Is it better now?

Comment: @geetha290krm Obvious because $\mu(X) = \nu(X)$ ?

Comment: Much better. What goes wrong if you try to derive the hypothesis of the result you know (with increasing $F_i$) from the one you are given (with disjoint $F_i$) by converting the increasing sequence into a disjoint sequence: $F_1, F_2 \setminus F_1, \ldots$?

Comment: @RobArthan if i know that the measure of every Fi is finite then the measure of every Gi=Fi\F1U....UF_i-1 is also finite because its smaller and I'm done. But if start with an increasing sequence Fi and i know that i can create the disjoint sequence Gi for which the measure of evey Gi is finite and the measures are equal for every A in sigma algebra, then thats true for the measure of X and the measure of the countable union of the disjoint sets equals the lim as n goes to infinity of the measure of An but I'm not sure where that takes us.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n\in \mathbb N,$ let $\mathcal C_n = \{G\in \sigma(\mathcal F) : \mu(G\cap F_n) = \nu(G\cap F_n)\}.$ If we can show each $\mathcal C_n = \sigma(\mathcal F),$ we're done, since then, for any $G\in \mathcal \sigma(F),$ $\mu(G) = \sum_n \mu(G\cap F_n) = \sum_n \nu(G\cap F_n) = \nu(G).$

We have $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal C_n,$ so it suffices to show $\mathcal C_n$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. By Dynkin's theorem, it suffices to show that $\mathcal C_n$ contains $X$ and is closed under countable increasing unions and contained differences (i.e. $B\setminus A$ for $A\subseteq B).$ That it contains $X$ is clear, and closure under increasing unions follows from continuity of measure. For contained differences, if $A\subseteq B$ and $A,B\in \mathcal C_n,$ then since $\mu(F_n)=\nu(F_n)<\infty,$ $$\mu((B\setminus A)\cap F_n) = \mu(B\cap F_n)- \mu(A\cap F_n) = \nu(B\cap F_n)-\nu(A\cap F_n) = \nu((B\setminus A)\cap F_n)$$

Comment: thanks for the reply. I understood most of it but i have an issue with Cn being closed under countable increasing unions. The way to prove it would be to define Ai in Cn which form an increasing sequence? Then we would need to show that their union intersecting with Fn is in Cn, but how can we apply the continuity of measure there? Since the union of Ai intersecting with a random Fn is a bigger set than the interstection of each Ai with each Fn and then taking the union. Or we can just say that the union of Ai since its incresaing is just the limit of n to inf of An and An belongs to Cn?

Comment: @NoetherBoy Let $A = \bigcup_i A_i$ where $A_i$ are increasing and $A_i \in \mathcal C_n.$ Then $A_i \cap F_n$ are increasing with union $A\cap F_n.$ (It's always true that $(\bigcup_i X_i)\cap Y = \bigcup_i(X_i\cap Y).$) So $\mu(A\cap F_n) = \lim_i \mu(A_i\cap F_n) = \lim_i \nu(A_i\cap F_n) = \nu(A\cap F_n).$

Comment: God I'm such an idiot! I was using the same notation on my paper for Ai and Fn(both with n) and i couldn't undesrtand for the life of me why we intersect with each Fn. Thanks for the reply